# write output of Sqlcmd to txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am 100% new to batch files, so bear with me.

```
sqlcmd -U %username% -P %pw% -S ServerName -d DBName -i "%%G" >> output.txt
```

This doesn't work. It works fine without the `>>`. The error is:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file >> (Reason: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Update:

Although it doesn't solve the question as asked, a solution was found... something like this:

```
FOR %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
    ECHO STARTED: "%%G" >CON
    sqlcmd -U %username% -P %pw% -S ServerName -d DBName -i "%%G"
    ECHO FINISHED: "%%G" >CON
) >> output.txt
```

Comment: Can you use the -o option to specify the output file?

Comment: @MarkLeiber I need it to append, is the problem; otherwise I could.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit, which invalidated my comment. I deleted my comment before I saw your reply to it.

Comment: I created two files (file1.sql and file2.sql) in a directory where I have your script in a batch file.  The .sql files just do 'SELECT 1;' and 'SELECT 2;'.  When I ran the batch file, it correctly appended the output of the SELECT statements to output.txt.  Maybe there's something about the value of %%G in your loop or the contents of one of your files.

Comment: You could put `>>output.txt` before `sqlcmd`.  `>> output.txt sqlcmd -U %username% etc`.  Also, try `echo %%G` to make sure `%%G` has the value you intend.

Comment: I think you need to post more of your bat file if anyone is to be able to help. Clearly something is going wrong with the for loop, in fact I think your %%G parameter must actually be >>.  (I also hope -d TableName is a typo and you're actually putting a database name there instead)